# How do I prevent Shared Photo stream

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, photo-stream

I have recently bought an iPhone 6s and transferred my 5c to another family member. I have updated both photo libraries of both phones to my Macbook Air. My problem is that all photos appear on each device at any time, and if I delete a photo from any device then it is deleted from them all, (with or without a cable connection). I would like to use the Macbook as a library for both phones, but keep different photos on each phone.
How do I do this without losing any photos now?

Comment: Do you have different AppleIds on the two phones?

Comment: No, same Id, maybe I have to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up separate Apple Ids for each user, possibly using [Family Sharing](https://www.apple.com/uk/icloud/family-sharing/) to share purchases and other things.

A simple iCloud id, which is what you have, assumes you want everything syncronised between all your devices.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to turn off iCloud Photo sharing on the 5c (Settings > iCloud); this will break the 5c's connection to synchronization of the two phones and the Mac, so that only the Mac and the 6s will synch. The 5c will ask if you wish to keep or discard the photos that are already on it. Photos subsequently added to the Mac or the 6s will not appear on the 5c.